# Will Initialization Vectors grow in size in the future?

Tags: cryptography, aes, initialization-vector

I'm currently using AES (256) with CBC mode to encrypt data. I store the initialization vector with the encrypted data. Right now I'm just adding the IV to the beggining of the encrypted data, then on decrypt, reading it in as a *hard coded* length of bytes.

If the initialization vector length changes in the future, this method will break.

So my questions is:

Will longer AES key sizes in the future = longer IVs? Or, in other words, will the block size of AES change in the future?

If so, what would be the best way of dealing with this? Using the first byte as an indicator of how long the IV is, then reading in that many bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rijndael does support larger block sizes, but AES is currently fixed at a 128 bit block. It seems relatively unlikely that the larger Rijndael block sizes will be standardized by NIST, since this would effectively be a completely new algorithm, one that hasn't been implemented by anyone. If NIST feels the need for block cipher with a larger size, it's likely the would simply run a new contest.

However what I would recommend is that, rather than the IV length, you include near the start of your message some kind of algorithm identifier (a single byte is all you'll need), which will allow you not just the flexibility to handle larger IVs, but also extend your format in other ways in the future, for instance a new algorithm. Eg 0 == AES-256/CBC, 1 == AES-256/GCM, 2=AES-2.0/CBC, 3=AES-256/CBC with special extra header somewhere, etc, etc.

PS - don't forget to also use a message authentication code, since otherwise you expose yourself to a variety of easy message modification attacks.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the initialization vector is to randomize the first block, so that the same data encrypted twice with the same key will not produce the same output.

From an information-theoretic point of view, there are "only" 2^128 distinct IVs for AES, because those are all the possible random values you might XOR with your first block of actual data.  So there is never any reason to have an IV larger than the cipher's block size.

Larger block sizes could justify larger IVs.  Larger key sizes do not.

A larger block size would mean a different algorithm by definition.  So however you tag your data to indicate what algorithm you are using, that is how you will tell what block size (and therefore IV size) to use.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you could switch to AES-CTR mode.  Counter mode requires a Nonce, but the Nonce does not have to be tied to the AES block size.  If the AES block size were increased (unlikely, as Jack says) then you could retain the same size Nonce.